# CKEditor: Removing 'Display Text' from 'Link' dialog leads to unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to remove the 'Display Text' part of the 'Link' dialog in CKEdit.

This is how it currently looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgTuV.png

I tried editing the 'config.js' file to get rid of it, like this:

```
if (dialogName == 'link') {
    // Remove the 'Advanced' and 'Target' tabs from the 'Link' dialog.        
    dialogDefinition.removeContents('advanced');
    dialogDefinition.removeContents('target');

    // Get a reference to the 'Link Info' tab.
    var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');

    // Remove unnecessary widgets from the 'Link Info' tab.         
    infoTab.remove('linkDisplayText');
}
```

However, the outcome looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iihxd.png

The 'Display Text' field was removed as expected, but lots of different fields appeared. Seems to be the fields that show up depending on what you choose in the 'Link Type' drop-down list.

Chrome's console also threw an error:

```
link.js?t=G87E:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElement' of undefined
```

How can I fix this (preferably without messing with the source code)?

Cheers

Comment: try to make it invisible, instead of removing it

Comment: Hmm, I would prefer a cleaner solution. Something seems to be wrong since the console throws an error - I will try it out though if I can't find another way to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, how would you do it? I can't really use CSS since I can't access or change the html code CKEdit generates.

Comment: You can access the generated css with jquery or javascript. You should be able to inspect this, find the relevant dialogue markup and then apply the style to the necessary classes when ckeditor is instantiated. It's not pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Configuration helper plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/confighelper) to hide it, but you should file a ticket because most of the people won't want that field (they added in the latest "minor" release but they don't even think about it for CKEditor 5: http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-Biweekly-for-October-5-2016 )

They should adjust the new code so it doesn't fail if the people have removed the field because they don't want it.